# OAuth implementation for web application 

Tags: web-applications, architecture, authentication, oauth

The setup is this: I have a web application built for organizations.  These organizations can have a single username and password the log into their customized system or they can have multiple usernames and passwords with varying permissions in their system.  We have been storing usernames and passwords in our own database, but are looking into using OAuth so users can log into their system via their Twitter, Facebook, GMail, etc. credentials (and so we can access their profiles, contacts, etc.)  All users come to the same login page.

**My question is this:**

Using OAuth, how do I get them logged into the correct system with the correct permissions?

Would they log in normally (using credentials for my web app), and then need a place to specify 'I want to allow Twitter account "Example123" access to this system'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each username and password in your current database will correspond to a user id from each service provider in your future database. for example:

```
user_id | group_id | username | password | twitter_user_id | facebook_user_id | google_user_id
1001    | 3003     | fred     | abc123   | aaaaaaaa        | bbbbbbbb         | ccccccc
```

with a structure like this you can continue to use your existing login mechanism as well as allowing users to link their facebook/twitter/etc accounts to their current login. i'm assuming you have some form of user id and group id already set up in your database, but if not then i think this would be the easiest route to take.

there are a lot of different methods to link existing accounts to the users' various service provider accounts - its really up to you to choose one which fits well with your existing structure and provides the most seamless experience for your users. one possible oauth flow for your website whereby a user can link a new service provider to their account might be:

- user navigates to login screen on your site
- user logs in using their original username and password
- user selects a service provider (eg twitter) to link to their account
- user is redirected to twitter
- user enters their twitter password on the twitter oauth screen and agrees to allow your website to access whatever information you have said you will need
- twitter then redirects the user back to your oauth callback page
- you take the returned twitter id (and whatever other information twitter returns) and place it in your database against this user
- the user can now login using only twitter in future

once the user has enabled one service provider they then have two means of accessing the same account.

in addition to the above process, i recommend adding an audit trail so that users can see the actions which have been taken with their account. this might depend on the time you have available but it is likely to safe you many painful hours of customer support down the track. the more information you can tell your users, and the more power you give them to manage this information, the less investigation you will have to do yourself, and the less time you will have to spend fixing your users problems for them.

Comment: Thanks. I will structure the tables a little different.  I will have a "user" table and an "identity" table because there may be a user "User123" that needs to allow access to more than one Twitter account (for example).